# RelativeLayout alignment rules don't work in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, dialogfragment

I have an about dialog with `RelativeLayout`. It works correctly in ordinary activity, but when I decided to move it into `DialogFragment`, most of alignment rules stopped working. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="250dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_copyright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Copyright (c) 2013 Copyright"
        android:textSize="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/label_copyright"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/label_version"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Application Name"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_app_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/label_app_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/field_public_required" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label_copyright"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="application description with more details" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how it should work, and it does actually work so when in an activity (Eclipse graphical layout screenshot):

[image]

And here is how it looks in running application with fragments:

[image]

Apparently, only the first view is centered as expected, while all the others are just pushed to the top. No matter which `minHeight` I specify in the layout, the behaviour is always the same.

The code to instantiate the dialog is very simple:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null);

    try
    {
      TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_version);
      t.setText(getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
    }
    catch(NameNotFoundException e)
    {
    }

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(view)
    .setTitle(R.string.about)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
      {
      }
    }
    )
    .create();
}
```

What is wrong with it and how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinearLayout`? Would be perfect for that case.

Comment: @grexter89, I will possibly try this as a workaround. But the fact is that I used this layout in a couple of my previous apps and I wanted just to insert it as is into a DialogFragment. Shouldn't it work anyway?

Comment: I would advise moving all of your textSize and layout dimensions to `dimen.xml` it will be much easier to maintain a uniform spaced layout and text sizes for your application.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same bug. We ended up doing something REALLY hacky to get it to work:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:id="@+id/layout_form_field">
    <Button android:layout_below="@id/layout_form_field"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, just nest your RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout... #silly

Comment: Great. You've helped me with this stupid android bug (Still not fixed on android Lollipop!). Also guys note that both relative and linear wrapper should have match_parent sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your XML layout to :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center">
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewApplicationImage"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewApplicationName"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewApplicationDescription"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewApplicationCopyright"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What the important part here is setting the `gravity` attribute so all your Widgets will be centered in the view. The `gravity` attribute sets the positioning of the child views for the linear layout.